# Ubuntu detects a fake monitor each reboot

Tags: monitor

When I turn on the Ubuntu, it detects a monitor that does not exist and I must desactive it each time I log in my session:

[image]

What can I do to delete permanently this fake monitor?
The system is Ubuntu 14.04 GNOME